# Why do I have multiple gitignore files?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I'm new to using git and github. I've been using it to keep tabs on different versions of some of my code, and I've been using the github desktop app to manage things. Just to complicate things, I'm jumping between two different PCs - I'm writing the code locally on my home PC, but running it remotely on my work office PC (because my home PC is old and slow).

I've been editing the "gitignore" file so that the output files produced by the code are ignored. I do this through the desktop app (Repository/Repository settings/Ignored Files).

However, what is confusing me is that

- I somehow end up with multiple gitignore files being generated (gitignore,gitignore2,gitignore3...etc.)

and

- Each time the most recent gitignore file does not keep the rules I entered previously instructing that certain file types should be ignored.

Since I'm new I don't have any idea of why this is happening or even where to start looking. If anyone can provide any advice that would be great. All I want to do is have a single gitignore file that keeps a record of what file extension types to ignore.

Comment: Are you syncing things using some sort of cloud syncing service, like Dropbox or similar?

Comment: Hi, yes, apologies I answered my own question before I saw your response. That indeed was the issue - if I put the repo in a folder that is not monitored by the cloud sync service everything seems fine.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Yeah, definitely don't use cloud-syncing services for repositories.  They do this kind of stuff and also can corrupt repositories.

Comment: Thanks again for confirming that. I've been working out of the cloud-synced folders on my PC since I've been working from home during lockdown. It never occurred to me that this could be an issue for Git but I'll make sure to avoid it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after hours of banging my head against a wall I seemingly figured out the issue.

It seems there is some sort of issue with ShareFile app on my PC, which is the Dropbox-style app that my work uses to backup and sync folders. If I create or clone a repo in a folder monitored by ShareFile then the ".gitignore" files get somehow changed/corrupted to "gitignore" files (the . gets dropped). Subsequently the Github desktop app then doesn't properly recognise the file and that leads to gitignore being duplicated/ignored.

If the repo is in a folder that isn't monitored by ShareFile then there is no problem.